# Why is the 'GPU compute' render option blurred out for me?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I think it would be faster to render with my gpu, but I can't seem to select it.

My GPU is an MSI gtx 1050 ti

[image]

Comment: please [edit] your question and add what GPU you have. What does the "Cycles compute device" in the system tab of the user preferences say??

Comment: @David I just set it to CUDA it works now, it's only about 14 seconds faster though. Is it common for people to use their gpu or cpu?

Comment: if you have a good gpu then use it! 1050ti is a  decent card, not super powerful, but like you saw even that can out perform a cpu.

Comment: PS please do not add "Solved" to a question. It would be better if you wrote an answer, and explained what you did to turn on GPU rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to open the **"User Preferences"**.

Switch to the **"System"** tab and change your *compute device*.

[image]

*(I do not have a compatible GPU, but yours should show up here, if it is compatible.)*

I recommend clicking **"Save User Settings"** so that this is saved for next time you open a new Blender file.

Your GPU should now appear under the GPU compute section.